# Customize flyspell (ispell) dictionary

Tags: spell-checking, ispell

I know how to add custom words to ispell, but I would like to remove certain words from the dictionary. For example, although `ass` and `asses` are correct words, I rarely type them, and would like to flag them as likely typos to `as` and `assess`.

Where does ispell store its dictionary? The man page does not provide the location. Also, the man page makes it seem like there are a lot of steps to build a new dictionary, and it isn't just an ASCII file where I can remove certain words. Any advice how to build a new dictionary without a given word?

**Edit**

From some hints on: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch29_05.htm

It seems like I can start with /usr/share/dict/words, remove the words I don't want, and then make a new ispell dictionary from that. However, I'm having trouble making the new dictionary. `buildhash` is the key program here, but it wants an affixfile, and I do not know how to generate that file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this for `aspell`.

1. Create a **sorted** file `aspell_no` containing words you do NOT want spell check to recognize.
2. Run the following code:

> ```
> aspell dump master | sort > aspell_master
> comm -2 -3 aspell_master ~/.aspell_words_list_no > better_master
> aspell --lang=en create master ./custom < better_master
> sudo cp custom `aspell config dict-dir`
> ```

Test it:

```
echo "some words I do not want spell check to recognize" > test.txt
cat test.txt |aspell list --master=custom
```

Get it working in emacs (may need to restart flyspell or emacs to get this to work):

```
(setq ispell-program-name "aspell")
(setq ispell-list-command "list")
(setq ispell-extra-args '("--master=custom"))
```